# Using row_number() in subquery results in ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: sql, oracle, ranking, row-number

In Oracle, I wish to do something like the SQL below.   For each row in "criteria," I want to find the latest row in another table (by last_modified_date) for the same location_id, and use that value to set default_start_interval.  Or, if there is no such value, then use 30.  However, as you can see, the subquery must have two values in the select statement to use row_number(). That causes an error.  How do I reformat it so that it works?

```
update criteria pc set default_start_interval = 
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT start_interval, 
                row_number() over(partition by aday.location_id 
                                  order by atime.last_modified_date desc
                             ) as rn
            FROM available_time atime 
            JOIN available_day aday ON aday.available_day_id = atime.available_day_id
            WHERE aday.location_id = pc.location_id
                and rn = 1)
        , 30)
```

Comment: I believe you might be overdoing it with the solution if I understood correctly. Not sure though if you insiste on using the technique in your question or would you be open to an alternative SQL solution (which I believe might be simpler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your update query:

1. The update expects only one value per row for default_start_interval, however, you have two columns in the select list.
2. The row number should be assigned before in the inner query, and then apply filter `where rn = 1` in outer query.

Your update query should look like:

```
UPDATE criteria pc
SET default_start_interval = NVL(
    (
    SELECT start_interval FROM(
        SELECT
            start_interval, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY aday.location_id 
                ORDER BY atime.last_modified_date DESC
            ) AS rn
        FROM
            available_time atime
            JOIN available_day aday ON aday.available_day_id = atime.available_day_id
        WHERE
            aday.location_id = pc.location_id
        )
    WHERE rn = 1)
    , 30)
```

**Note:** You could simply use `NVL` instead of `COALESCE` as you only have one value to check for NULL. COALESCE is useful when you have multiple expressions.

Comment: . . I think Oracle will error out on the correlation clause because it is nested two levels deep.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I thought that the JOIN wouldn't work on the nested subquery too, but it worked.  I don't understand how that error works apparently.   Thanks for the solution Lalit.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simpler method uses aggregation and `keep` to get the value you want:

```
update criteria pc
    set default_start_interval = 
            (select coalesce(max(start_interval) keep (dense_rank first order by atime.last_modified_date desc), 30)
             from available_time atime join
                  available_day aday 
                  on aday.available_day_id = atime.available_day_id
             where aday.location_id = pc.location_id
            );
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP` always returns one row.  If no rows match, then the returned value is `NULL` -- the `COALESCE()` captures this case.

Comment: Looks like this one does the same thing.  I find Lalit's method easier to understand though.  Just a personal choice.

Comment: @dougd_in_nc . . . I disagree with which is easier to understand (a simple aggregation or multiple nested subqueries and selects), but that is a matter of opinion.  More importantly, Oracle usually balks at nested correlation clauses so I'm surprised that query even works.